# Ubuntu UI response lag, but mouse moves smoothly

Tags: ubuntu, lag, ubuntu-18.04

Tried to record my problem: https://youtu.be/ccLoV_hGm6M
The complete GUI of my ubuntu 18.04 system is running slowly with extreme response lags. However, the mouse is running smoothely, so there might be no issue with my AMD graphics card.
Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: I can't give you an exact cause, but I recommend switching to a lighter DE such as Xfce (try Xubuntu as a live USB first) and it should be much smoother. It is more lightweight and responsive, although it may lack fancy cosmetic and other functional features that you may have to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: my monitor was connected with a HDMI cable. Switched to VGA and now there are no lags. Weird, but it works.